# QtCreator is failing to run CMake after updating

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I've been using QtCreator as my CMake IDE for a long time in Ubuntu. Today I was notified there was an update. So I updated and it looks like I can't compile CMake projects anymore.

This is the error I get when I run CMake from the IDE.

```
error: The source directory "/tmp/QtCreator-jNrmHx/qtc-cmake-OgPpycUx" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Is the file it is looking for in /tmp/QtCreator-jNrmHx/qtc-cmake-OgPpycUx actually exist?

Comment: There were significant changes in CMake support https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-4.13-released.

Comment: @NickM. No, the folder is empty.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov Thanks, there is a comment saying ""Warning: this update requires CMake 3.14+ without server-mode, which may break your projects if you attempt to change some CMake property that contains "" in the description, due to QTCREATORBUG-24401."" That could be my problem since my Ubuntu 18.04 works with CMake 3.10.2

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when setting up a new build config with QtC 4.14.
In "CMake Initial parameters", make sure that there is no empty lines, and that each option is one per line. I then deleted the temp source folder re-ran CMake.